# Could not compute a complete dependency map for the project

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

i would like to get rid of this message so build time dramatically decreases (it builds and runs ok).
This warning appears in mtouch.

> warning MT3006: Could not compute a complete dependency map for the
>   project. This will result in slower build times because Xamarin.iOS
>   can't properly detect what needs to be rebuilt (and what does not need
>   to be rebuilt). Please review previous warnings for more details.

Test solution: helloworld mvvmcross solution with ios project and pcl (wp8+monotouch+net45+android) + Microsoft HTTP PCL package in pcl only + an async call to HttpClient.GetStringAsync in the pcl.

Full log:

> warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' of the assembly
>   'Cirrious.CrossCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=e16445fd9b451819' was not found. Please review the
>   project's references.
>
> ```
> warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' of the assembly
> ```
>
> 'Cirrious.MvvmCross, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=e16445fd9b451819' was not found. Please review the
>   project's references.
>
> ```
> warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' of the assembly
> ```
>
> 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' was not found. Please review the project's
>   references.
>
> ```
> warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Net.Primitives, Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' of
> ```
>
> the assembly 'Com.Catenum.Intouch.Business, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was not found. Please review the
>   project's references.
>
> ```
> warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' of the assembly
> ```
>
> 'Com.Catenum.Intouch.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' was not found. Please review the project's
>   references.
>
> ```
> warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' of
> ```
>
> the assembly 'Com.Catenum.Intouch.Business, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was not found. Please review the
>   project's references.
>
> ```
> warning MT3006: Could not compute a complete dependency map for the project. This will result in slower build times because
> ```
>
> Xamarin.iOS can't properly detect what needs to be rebuilt (and what
>   does not need to be rebuilt). Please review previous warnings for more
>   details.

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that all the assemblies only reference BCL assemblies that Xamarin.iOS ships.

For example:

```
warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' of the assembly 'Com.Catenum.Intouch.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was not found. Please review the project's references.
```

Xamarin.iOS does not have a System.Net.Http v1.5.0.0, it has v2.0.5.0 instead (all the Xamarin.iOS base class libraries have version v2.0.5.0, except monotouch.dll itself). The solution is to recompile Com.Catenum.Intouch.Business as a Xamarin.iOS class library (this typically involves creating a new Xamarin.iOS class library project, and link the source files in), which will ensure it contains the correct reference to System.Net.Http.dll.

Note that in Xamarin.iOS 7.0.4 there is a (harmless) bug which causes spurious MT3005/3006 warnings in some cases. This is probably the case for the first warning:

```
warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' of the assembly 'Cirrious.CrossCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e16445fd9b451819' was not found. Please review the project's references.
```

since Xamarin.iOS does contain a System.Windows assembly with that version.